# Is SITE_KEY in a table in the database?

Tags: civicrm.settings

I've cloned a website to make it a sandbox and I changed the site key in civicrm.settings.php following [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/548/changing-civicrm-site-key-in-the-civicrm-settings-php-file).

My question is: do I also need to change this value in some table in the database?

Answer (score 2):

No. As far as I'm aware the sole entry is in civicrm.settings.php

Comment: ok thanks Graham